# Animation get interrupted before finish

Tags: android, android-animation

What i'm trying to achieve is translation animation with regard to scrolling.

My RelativeLayout is wrapped with custom ScrollView.

My onScrollChanged function is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onScrollChanged (ScrollView who, int l, int t, int oldL, int oldT) { 
   if(t > oldT){
        someView.animate.translationYBy(-2f);
   } else{
        someView.animate.translationYBy(2f);
   }
}
```

Problem is that the animation get canceled each time because other animation starts before the previous finishes.

> Android doc: Animations already running on the property will be canceled.

Is there any way around it?

Thanks and a big thumbs up for the helper